# not able to run insert function in php

Tags: php, html

**1.** I am not not able to insert the data which is coming from array into database.

**2.** I made a class of db controller in that define two functions one for fetching the data and another for inserting the data out of that one is working one is not..

This my insert function:

```
function insertQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
}
```

**PHP**

```
case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
        $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"],'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    $db_handle->insertQuery("INSERT INTO addToCart (code,name,quantity,price) VALUES
                    ($itemArray["code"],$itemArray["name"],$itemArray["quantity"],$itemArray["price"])");
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? Be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I see a lot of code, but no question.

Comment: Hi, Rohit, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: first thing 1)- i am not not able to insert the data which is coming from array into databse 2)_- i made a class of db controller in that define two functions one for fetching the data and another for inserting the data out of that one is workin one is not..
 function insertQuery($query) {
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
 } this my insert function

Comment: Have you ran code in example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: if harcord the values the data is easily inserted but when 6the data which had been coming from array it is not going    here db controller page

Comment: if harcord the values the data is easily inserted but when 6the data which had been coming from array it is not going    here db controller page    
}if(!empty($resultset))return $resultset;}function insertQuery($query{$result = mysql_query($query);}
function numRows($query) {$result  = mysql_query($query);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
return $rowcount;}}

Comment: @ROHITJHA Update your question with the information. It's difficult to read the code when it's spread out across multiple comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are throwing off the encapsulation. You can get around it like this:

```
$db_handle->insertQuery("INSERT INTO addToCart (code,name,quantity,price) VALUES
                ({$itemArray["code"]},{$itemArray["name"]},{$itemArray["quantity"]},{$itemArray["price"]})");
```

However, since it seems like you're using some sort of database wrapper, look for a way to bind variables instead.

Comment: anyone plze help me out with this code...........is strugling since i am new

Comment: I see now that you're using mysql_* functions. Those are deprecated and removed as of PHP7. Do not use them. Look into tutorials for PDO and mysqli, and use their functions to bind the parameters. If you insist on going forward with this code, try what I suggested. If it does not work, please provide more information.